# E/StubController : activity is null

Tags: android

I am working with a service and I get an error :
E/StubController : activity is null.
I get this error with a Huawei phone but not with a Sony phone.
I don't want to post my code here because it's long and may be boring.
And also because I don't looking for a debugger.
I just want to know what is a StubController and where can I find a documentation on this.

Thanks in advance,

Kr.